# How to make Mac app archive signed?

Tags: macos, xcode4

I want to publish my Mac app to Mac App Store.

So I've tried to sign my app and archive with Xcode 4.

I got the process to sign the app - build settings.

However, I don't know how to sign archive(package).

In Organizer, when I tried to submit with archive, identity drop box shows that "No valid signing identities found" and others aren't showed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need to create installation package certificate here: http://developer.apple.com/certificates/index.action
2. download newly created certificate and double click it to install
3. Restart XCode if it was launched

UPDATED: And guys! One more thing! Don't use beta SDK. The itunes connect wouldn't accept such binary.

Comment: RESTART XCODE! That's the imortant part.

Answer (score 0):

You need the INSTALLER and the APPLICATION certificate for this. And restarting is important, Remizorrr is right!